# babel installation failing, client path missing

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm attempting to do the following [babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) installation.

```
$ mkdir babel-test
$ cd babel-test
$ npm init
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

At this point, I've got the following tree.

```
├── package.json
├── node_modules
│   ├── babel-cli
│       ├── etc...
```

And at this point, I think I'm good to go. But I get this error.

```
$ babel
=> -bash: /usr/local/bin/babel: No such file or directory
```

These are the contents of my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "babel-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.0"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Of course, it looks like it isn't looking in the correct directory for babel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to install it locally to your project, you'll have to reference it via the absolute path in the node_modules directory:

`./node_modules/.bin/babel`

Check out the usage section in the docs. It gives an example of setting up an npm script which might be your best option.

https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli

Alternatively, you could use some build tool (such as grunt or gulp) to set up a service that watches the files you want to transpire for changes and have the traspile occur on file change events.

Comment: thank you sir, that worked. I wish it they had mentioned all that on the page dedicated to setting up the babel client.